# Odd behavior of GroebnerBasis

Tags: algebra

I have a parametric equation like following:

```
expr = {1/(4 (1 + t^2)^3) - (15 t^2)/(4 (1 + 
          t^2)^3) + (15 t^4)/(4 (1 + t^2)^3) - t^6/(4 (1 + t^2)^3) + 
    3/(4 (1 + t^2)) - (3 t^2)/(4 (1 + 
         t^2)), -((3 t)/(2 (1 + t^2)^3)) + (5 t^3)/(1 + 
        t^2)^3 - (3 t^5)/(2 (1 + t^2)^3) + (3 t)/(2 (1 + 
         t^2)), (2 Sqrt[3] t)/(1 + t^2)^2 - (2 Sqrt[3] t^3)/(1 + 
        t^2)^2};
ParametricPlot3D[expr, {t, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now I want to turn this into an implicit equation. So I use `GroebnerBasis`:

```
bases = GroebnerBasis[Thread[Equal[{x,y,z},expr]],{},t]
```

> {9 x y - Sqrt[3] z^3, -1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2}

I can show it with `ContourPlot3D`:

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[bases == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  Mesh -> None], 
 ParametricPlot3D[expr, {t, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Magenta]]]
```

[image]

This is a very good result. But I cannot understand why `GroebnerBasis[Thread[Equal[{x,y,z},expr]],{x,y,z},t]` cannot get the same result? And I can't even find the useage of `GroebnerBasis[Thread[Equal[{x,y,z},expr]],{},t]` in documentation.

As far as I know, the *Gröbner Basis* of the polynomial idea is unique, but the result returned by the two expressions is obviously not the same ideal. Is there any bug in it?

Comment: @RolandF As far as I know, the ideal of a polynomial is unique, how can one be of length 2 and one of length 4? Or do you think there are extra bases in a base of length 4? Doesn't fit the definition of a `GroebnerBasis`, does it?

Comment: The normal way is Eliminate@Reduce and yields a complete list of special solutions. GroebnerBasis without variables and elimination of "t" treats all symbols as the polynomial  variables. Specifying  {x,y,z} in eliminations yields more polynomials, the last two beeing identical to the empty list. GroebnerBasis makes  random walk that may different on different input.

Comment: @RolandF Can you get any results from this code? `Eliminate[Thread[Equal[{x,y,z},expr]],t]`

Comment: What is the actual question? - "Why ... cannot get the same result?" - Same as what? In what sense the same? You cannot have a single implicit equation of a curve in 3D. All equations in 3 variables represent a surface in 3D (except some degenerate cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Documented or undocumented?**

According to the docs(!), `GroebnerBasis[Thread[Equal[{x,y,z},expr]],{},t]` treats the expressions as polynomials in `t` with the omitted variables `x`, `y`, `z` treated as "parameter variables."  According to the docs, the parameter variables will be inferred from variables missing in the specified variables, if they are not explicitly declared with the `ParameterVariables` option.  The following give the same output:

```
GroebnerBasis[{x, y, z} - expr, {x, y, z}, t, 
 MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]

(*  {-1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2, -3 Sqrt[3] x y + z^3}  *)

GroebnerBasis[{x, y, z} - expr, {t, x, y, z}, t, 
 MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder, ParameterVariables -> {x, y, z}]

(*  {-1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2, -3 Sqrt[3] x y + z^3}  *)
```

The above basis is not the same as but is clearly equivalent to the basis returned in one of the OP's codes:

```
GroebnerBasis[{x, y, z} - expr, {}, t]

(*  {9 x y - Sqrt[3] z^3, -1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2}  *)
```

As others have mentioned, the basis depends on the ordering.  See for instance [Monomial Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order) or google it. Specifying `{x, y, z}` puts `x` first, so, for example, the first element of the basis has the lowest degree in `x` (zero, in this case). If you specify the order `{y, z, x}`, then the first element of the basis has the lowest degree in `y`. This is not the only property of a Groebner basis, of course, and it is meant to point out only that the order of the variables makes a difference.

Also, there are (at least) three types of variables, ordinary ones, ones to be eliminated, and parameter variables. And despite the documentation implying that omitted variables are treated like explicitly declared `ParameterVariables`, it is unclear to me that that is actually true. A possible fourth type of variable are the numeric constants that are not strictly speaking numbers.  In the OP's problem, that includes `Sqrt[3]`. How these types affect the algorithm is unknown to me.

**Where the difference turns up**

There is an undocumented internal function that can reduce the basis. For instance, `GroebnerBasis[{x, y, z} - expr, {}, t]` first produces the `GroebnerBasis[{x, y, z} - expr, {x, y, z}, t]` basis, and then calls the following:

```
GroebnerBasis`Interreduce[
 {-27 y^2 + 27 y^4 + 27 y^2 z^2 + z^6, -3 Sqrt[3] y + 3 Sqrt[3] y^3 + 
   3 Sqrt[3] y z^2 + x z^3, 9 x y - Sqrt[3] z^3, -1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2},
 {}, t,
 {CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions, Modulus -> 0, 
  MonomialOrder -> Lexicographic, ParameterVariables -> {}, 
  Tolerance -> 0}]

(*  {9 x y - Sqrt[3] z^3, -1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2}  *)
```

**Some types of variables:**

```
traceDump1 = Trace[
   GroebnerBasis[{x, y, z} - expr, {}, t],
   TraceInternal -> True];
DeleteDuplicates@
 Cases[traceDump1,
  _Solve`SolvVar | _Solve`ElimVar | _Solve`ParmVar | 
  _Solve`RecipVar | _Solve`RadVar,
  Infinity]
(*
{Solve`ElimVar[t], Solve`RecipVar[1/(1 + Solve`ElimVar[t]^2)], 
 Solve`SolvVar[x], Solve`SolvVar[y], Solve`ParmVar[Sqrt[3]], 
 Solve`SolvVar[z]}
*)
```

You can see how the variables are tagged. Some of these are eliminated as the given system is converted to a polynomial system (such as `RecipVar[]`). Note that  `x`, `y`, and `z` are not tagged `ParmVar[]`; but they are if you specify `ParameterVariables -> {x, y, z}`. It's not clear whether these tags are used in computing the basis or only in preprocessing the input.

**The square-root variable**

It may be surprising that `Sqrt[3]` is treated as a variable.  For that reason, I wish to point out a couple of things that might not be of central importance to the OP's question.
You can include `Sqrt[3]` in the list of variables. For instance, `{x, Sqrt[3], y, z}` gives a different Groebner basis than `{x, y, z}`. If we include it in the variables to be eliminated, the result is disappointing and has the wrong dimension (maybe a bug?):

```
GroebnerBasis[{x, y, z} - expr, {x, y, z}, {t, Sqrt[3]}]

(*  {-1 + 3 x^2 - 3 x^4 + x^6 + 3 y^2 + 21 x^2 y^2 + 3 x^4 y^2 - 3 y^4 + 
  3 x^2 y^4 + y^6}  *)
```

But I've had trouble with over-eliminating before. If we're going to eliminate two variables, I should start with four equations. But it's hard to get a rational polynomial relation for `Sqrt[3]` that does not automatically evaluate to `0`; for instance `Sqrt[3]^2 - 3` does not work.  But we can use an indirect method:

```
GroebnerBasis[
 Join[{x, y, z} - expr, {a - Sqrt[3], a^2 - 3}],
 {x, y, z}, {t, Sqrt[3], a}]

(*  {-27 y^2 + 27 y^4 + 27 y^2 z^2 + z^6, -1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2}  *)
```

Comment: How do explain this example: `expr={x,y,z}-{t,Sqrt[2]t^2,t^3};

GroebnerBasis[expr,{t,x,y,z},{t},ParameterVariables->{x,y,z}]
GroebnerBasis[expr,{},{t}]`, which give different results.

Comment: @Lacia `ParameterVariables` variables and implicit parameter variables are not treated the same, even though the docs imply they are. (Which I said above: "And despite the documentation implying that omitted variables are treated like explicitly declared `ParameterVariables`, it is unclear to me that that is actually true.")

Comment: Thx! I'm quite confused about `ParameterVariables `. It's mentioned in the option examples but without any detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The elimination procedure

```
 expr = {1/(4 (1 + t^2)^3) - (15 t^2)/(4 (1 + t^2)^3) + 
           (15 t^4)/(4 (1 + t^2)^3) - t^6/(4 (1 + t^2)^3) + 
                3/(4 (1 + t^2)) - (3 t^2)/(4 (1 +  t^2)), 
         -((3 t)/(2 (1 + t^2)^3)) + (5 t^3)/(1 + t^2)^3 -
              (3 t^5)/(2 (1 + t^2)^3) + (3 t)/(2 (1 + t^2)), 
         (2 Sqrt[3] t)/(1 + t^2)^2 - (2 Sqrt[3] t^3)/(1 +  t^2)^2};


          expr3 = Simplify[expr]
```

$$\left\{-\frac{\left(t^2-1\right)^3}{\left(t^2+1\right)^3},\ \ \frac{8 t^3}{\left(t^2+1\right)^3},\ -\frac{2 \sqrt{3} t \left(t^2-1\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\right\}$$

```
        expr4 = Reduce[Thread[expr3=={x,y,z}]
```

[image: reduce out]

```
  Eliminate[expr4,{t}]
```

[image: elimination out]

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but does it explain the strange behavior of the `GroebnerBasis`?

Answer (score 1):

`GroebnerBasis[Thread[Equal[{x,y,z},expr]],{x,y,z},t]` follows the documented usage and gives the correct result.

Let's see a simple example,

```
expr={t,t^2,t^3};
polys=Thread[Subtract[{x,y,z},expr]];

bases=GroebnerBasis[polys,{},{t}]
bases2=GroebnerBasis[polys,{x,y,z},{t}]

PolynomialReduce[#,bases,{x,y,z}]&/@bases2
```

In this example both give the correct result.

[image]

Now let's deform the coefficient slightly,

```
expr={t,Sqrt[2]t^2,t^3};
polys=Thread[Subtract[{x,y,z},expr]];

bases=GroebnerBasis[polys,{},{t}]
bases2=GroebnerBasis[polys,{x,y,z},{t}]

PolynomialReduce[#,bases,{x,y,z}]&/@bases2
```

[image]

Hence we know the Groebner basis `bases2=GroebnerBasis[polys,{x,y,z},{t}]` is correct in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$

Notice that the Groebner basis is only unique when fixing the order of monomials. I guess the undocumented usage `GroebnerBasis[polys,{},{t}]` uses some default order and coefficient ring. Or even worse, if the `MonomialOrder` inherits from the empty argument `{}`, the result could make no sense.

```
expr={t,Sqrt[2] t^2,t^3};
polys=Thread[Subtract[{x,y,z},expr]];

bases=GroebnerBasis[polys,{},{t}]
bases=GroebnerBasis[polys,{},{t},CoefficientDomain->Rationals]
bases=GroebnerBasis[polys,{},{t},CoefficientDomain->RationalFunctions]
```

[image]